# Neovim: How do I set guicursor to make the cursor blink?

Tags: vim

The cursor blinking is off by default in Neovim and I want it back. I have tried to apply different arguments to guicursor, but didn't succeed. Since I want it to blink the same way in every mode, I think, I need something with the letter 'a' in it.

Here's what I have tried so far:
`:set guicursor=a:blinkwait700-blinkon400-blinkoff250` (I also tried with 'i')
`:set guicursor=a:blinkon100` (as the opposite of a:blinkon0 which switches it off)

I've already looked into the help but it didn't help me unfortunately.

**Update:**

What is peculiar is that `:set guicursor=a:blinkon100` enables the blinking in gVim, but not in Neovim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `st` terminal by Suckless then that does not support cursor blinking I belive, otherwise if your terminal does support it try setting the option `let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE=1` in your `init.vim` file. You could also pass that on the command line such as `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE=1 nvim`.

Comment: Finally, at least someone replied. Thank you! No, it's not terminal, I'm talking about the gui version called `nvim-qt`.

Comment: Ah, in that case from my quick search of their github it seems like they still have an unresolved about the cursor blinking not being supported, see: [link](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/208)

Comment: great! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, if you wish to use another nvim GUI, you can take a look [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Related-projects) as they list a lot of other GUIs that will work with nvim, one of them may have the support you need.

Comment: Thanks you very much! l will look into it.

Answer (score 5):

From `neovim` 0.2 onwards, setting `guicursor` does achieve the desired effect:

```
" Enable blinking together with different cursor shapes for insert/command mode, and cursor highlighting:
  set guicursor=n-v-c:block,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr:hor20,o:hor50
  \,a:blinkwait700-blinkoff400-blinkon250-Cursor/lCursor
  \,sm:block-blinkwait175-blinkoff150-blinkon175
```

Find more by typing `:help 'guicursor'` from inside `nvim`.

For more info, see the official [wiki](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-change-cursor-shape-in-the-terminal)

Finally, if you use `st`, you can *patch* it to get this working:
https://st.suckless.org/patches/blinking_cursor/

EDIT: I noticed from the comments of the first answer that OP was talking about `nvim-qt`, for those interested in that, a fix for it has been [merged](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/pull/623) at the beginning of this year.

Comment: This works on neovim v0.5.0-787-g98024853f Xubuntu 20.04 in terminal mode.